# Google Spreadsheet change border and save node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
  client_email: configs.creds.client_email,
  private_key: configs.creds.private_key
});
await doc.loadInfo();
const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[index];
const rows = await sheet.getRows();
rows[1]["Email Address"] = 'Change Border to Red'
await rows[1].save();
```

How can i change the border of row one ?
I'm using google-spreadsheet library from npm,
is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to change the border of the cells on Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using [google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) with Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Flow:

The flow of the sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve cells. In this case, the cells of "A1:C5" on 1st tab are retrieved.
2. Set the border object to each cell.
3. Run the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, the borders of cells of "A1:C5" on 1st tab of the Spreadsheet are changed to red color with `SOLID_THICK`.

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
  client_email: configs.creds.client_email,
  private_key: configs.creds.private_key
});
await doc.loadInfo();

// I added below script.
const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];  // In this case, 1st tab is used.

// A1:C5
const range = {startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: 5, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 3};
await sheet.loadCells(range);
const baseStyle = {style: "SOLID_THICK", color: {red: 1}};
for (let r = 0; r < range.endRowIndex - range.startRowIndex; r++) {
  for (let c = 0; c < range.endColumnIndex - range.startColumnIndex; c++) {
    sheet.getCell(r, c).borders = {top: baseStyle, bottom: baseStyle, left: baseStyle, right: baseStyle};
  }
}
await sheet.saveUpdatedCells();
```

- In this sample script, I used the gridRange. But it seems that a1Notation can be also used.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using your script. If your script in your question doesn't work, please check the official document.

#### References:

- [Official document of google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/)
- [Cell Formatting](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-cell?id=cell-formatting)
- [Borders](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#Borders)

### Added:

- You want to change the border of a cell.

I think that above script can be also used for this situation. But you can also use the following script. In this case, the boreder of cell "B2" is changed.

#### Sample script:

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
  client_email: configs.creds.client_email,
  private_key: configs.creds.private_key
});
await doc.loadInfo();

// I added below script.
const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];  // In this case, 1st tab is used.

// B2
const cell = "B2";
await sheet.loadCells(cell);
const baseStyle = {style: "SOLID_THICK", color: {red: 1}};
sheet.getCellByA1(cell).borders = {top: baseStyle, bottom: baseStyle, left: baseStyle, right: baseStyle};
await sheet.saveUpdatedCells();
```

Comment: @Byron Mataya Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, You got my question 100%, Thank you and keep rocking!

Comment: where is the accept button? This will be helpful to the other devs

Comment: @Byron Mataya Thank you for your response.

Comment: This is great, been struggling to get this module to do this sort of thing for a while. @Tanaike can you provide examples where the whole sheet is set in one call, for example, defaultFormat.verticalAlignment, or wrapStrategy, rather than calling it on every cell?

Comment: @macasas Thank you for your comment. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. In order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. Also, other users can see your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?